# Canvas drawBitmap and memory

Tags: java, android, memory, canvas

I have a series of extremely large bitmaps that I am drawing in a loop over my page in my app. I am using Canvas.drawBitmap to do it. Does drawBitmap copy the bitmap into a new location in memory, or does it use the actual bitmap I'm passing to it? I need to make sure I'm not killing memory by making repeated calls to this.

Comment: I find canvas is just slow...

Comment: Check out: http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html

Comment: I don't really have another option. You see, I've overridden a com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView so I can do this drawing over a GoogleMap. My drawing takes place in the overridden dispatchDraw(Canvas) function. And please don't tell me to use Ground Overlays. I've tried them, and they are sure-fire memory killers.